# Painting $\mathbb R^+$ with two colors which sum of two same color numbers be the same.

Tags: abstract-algebra, analysis, functions, ideals

Can any one paint  $\mathbb R^+$ with two colors which sum of two numbers with the same color has the same color.
Additional condition: Both colors should be used.
I tried use Cauchy functions like ($f(x+y)=f(x)+f(y)$). But there was no result.

Comment: If $1$ is blue, does $1 + 1 = 2$ have to be blue?

Comment: I guess $0$ is not in $\mathbb R^+$, otherwise there is a trivial solution: $0$ red and everything else blue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pick any $\Bbb Q$-automorphism $\sigma$ of $\Bbb R$ (as a $\Bbb Q$-vector field) (preferrably not of the form $\sigma(x)= \lambda x$ with $\lambda \in \Bbb R^*$), color $x$ blue if $\sigma(x)>0$, and color $x$ red if $\sigma(x)<0$.

Comment: Is there any $\mathbb Q$-automorphism necessarily. Any reference can help me a lot too.

Comment: If you believe in the axiom of choice, there are lots of nontrivial $\Bbb Q$-automorphisms of $\Bbb R$.

Comment: you still have to prove that there exists one with $\sigma(\mathbb R^+)\cap \mathbb R^-\neq\emptyset$.